# How do i prevent visual studio from renaming my id attributes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-community

I have recently migrated to visual studio 2015 community and my JavaScript no longer works because visual studio 2015 renames id attributes based on their content placeholders for example `GridView1` will become `ContentPlaceholder1_ContentPlaceHolder2_GridView1` at runtime.

How do I turn this off, am using c# and asp.Net ?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting this after migrating to VS2015 ?

Comment: Migrated from ... ? ASP.NET 1.1?

Comment: The solution was created on visual studio 2010 and .Net Framework 3.5 and  yes am sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [`ClientIDMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to `Static`, f.e. via page directive:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#"  ClientIDMode="Static" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PageName.ascx.cs" Inherits="WepAppName.PageName" EnableViewState="false" %>
```